# RAD 7.5 & Grinder

Tags: rad, grinder

I am wondering if anyone has tried to integrate Grinder with RAD 7.5.

**Issue:** When trying to run my recorded jpython script from the Grinder TCP Proxy I get the following error in RAD 7.5

Details:

- RAD 7.5
- Grinder: 3.6

I tried creating a basic script and the same thing happened in RAD. I was wondering if anyone had this happen? Or if you had any luck setting up Grinder within RAD 7.5.

### Error Message:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot get the capability, performing dispose of the retransforming environment**

```
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.isRetransformClassesSupported0(Native Method)
at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.isRetransformClassesSupported(InstrumentationImpl.java:112)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
at net.grinder.engine.process.dcr.DCRContextImplementation.create(DCRContextImplementation.java:74)
at net.grinder.engine.process.GrinderProcess.run(GrinderProcess.java:309)
at net.grinder.engine.process.WorkerProcessEntryPoint.run(WorkerProcessEntryPoint.java:86)
at net.grinder.engine.process.WorkerProcessEntryPoint.main(WorkerProcessEntryPoint.java:58)
```

16/12/11 2:15:11 PM (process WMTN200411-0): 
**Error running worker process (Jython interpreter state not initialized. You need to call PySystemState.initialize or PythonInterpreter.initialize.)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some more research into this , it seems to be a problem related to Grinder and the RAD java compiler. Running the same scripts external though the Grinder agent I was able to make it run.

I hope to have some time this week and debug the issue using the grinder source.